# PHP mySQL votes this month?

Tags: php, mysql

**So I have a voting system.**
Everytime someone votes, it adds a new row to column called **'Votes'** with all details + date, time.

In admin panel, I want to add a feature that will say how many votes we have gained this month.

***How can I do this?***

**Maybe select ALL rows that date is not lower than CURDATE() + 30 DAYS, and if yes, delete them all ad the count how many rows we have?**

```
    public function votesThisMonth()
    {
        $this->query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM votes WHERE date<DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)");
        $result = $this->query->execute();

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Yep, that's the way. Except the delete. Why would you delete?

Comment: That way all records will still be in the db ad cause a big storage usage I think? or it doesn't matter?

Comment: How many votes are you talking about? You'd have to be in the millions, at least, before you had to worry about storage space becoming an issue.

Comment: make sure you have an index on the date field and it will be a long time until you need to worry about throwing out information for performance reasons. Another option would be to create a separate archive table to archive old the old data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to delete anything. MySQL can handle a lot of data quite easily. At my job we have half a billion rows in some tables.

In the query below just change the year and month to be the current month you want to query.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS num_votes
FROM
    tablename
WHERE
    YEAR(datecol) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
AND MONTH(datecol) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
```

Comment: Thanks! question: How do I convert month from name to int?

Comment: Do you mean from `May` to `5`?

Comment: Oh, I don't need it i think, MONTH(datecol) does it for me right? Edit: nevermind, I need to let it know the current year and month.

Comment: Thanks! And if I want to do last month results, do I have to do MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) - 1 , is that correct?